# Telegram bot, отслеживание геолокации по времени

Tags: python, telegram-bot, время, telegram, геолокация

Запрашиваю у человека геолокацию, обрабатываю её и делюсь с ним ближайшим кафе. Вопрос - человек заходит, например, через сутки, очевидно, что он может находиться в другом месте, как мне заново запросить у него геолокацию, если его не было N-ое количество времени?

Answer (score 1):

Спарси последние сообщение и посмотри время его отправления, после чего, сравни это время с текущим и, если прошло к примеру минут 120, то спроси заново.